# Filling null attributes with mean attributes of neighboring polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, missing-data, null

I have a layer of polygons, where in some polygons there is missing data (null). I would like to fill these missing attributes by the average attributes in neighboring polygons. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to start doing this will be to use the [Polygon Neighbors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool to determine the neighbors of each polygon.

There is detailed documentation on how [How Polygon Neighbors Works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-polygonneighbors-analysis-works.htm) because it is a very flexible tool.

If it does not do what you need then it should be possible to post-process the output using ArcPy cursors to do so.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. However, Polygon Neighbors just provides a table describing the neighboring relationship. The main question here is about how to deal with the missing data issue. I want to have the original layer to be filled with averages of neighbors where there are nulls.

Comment: What's the average of a text field? What's the average of a date field? Have you looked into ArcPy cursors?

Comment: I would like to choose only one field, which is float or integer, for which average is well defined.

Comment: @splinter it is enough to populate table by missing numeric. Use attribute join with original. Summarise it afterwards. "Single" click attitude is wrong sometimes (always?)